# How can I make sure MySQL is using all available memory?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, innodb

Dumb question: I have 4 gb of RAM and my dataset is around 500 mb. How can I make sure MySQL/InnoDB is keeping my dataset in RAM?

Comment: I find that simply running MySQL is usually sufficient to ensure that it consumes all available system memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MySQL Tuning Primer](https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer) gives you lots info and recommendations regarding your MySQL performance.  Keep in mind (and it will warn you), the instance should be running for a period of time to give you accurate feedback.

Comment: Offtopic: Do you know of an alternative for Windows?

Answer (score 6):

set the innodb_buffer_pool to 3G - InnoDB will load as much data it can in the buffer pool.

Answer (score 1):

Darhazer is right (I'd vote him up but don't have the rep points). It's generally recommended to set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 70-80% of memory although it's really more complicated than that since you need to account for how much RAM other parts of your system is actually using.